# How do i refresh the particular Section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` on my `ViewController` It has `n` number of sections where my first section always displays my *Wishlist* products **(Only based on show *Wishlist* option enabled in `SettingsController`)** Every time when i add a product to my *Wishlist* on my `DetailViewController` i'm triggering a `NSNotificatiion` to my `ViewController` where it will fetch *Wishlist* records.

My `numberOfRowsInSection:` always returns `1` because, it is a `UITableView + UICollectionView` combination to produce *Horizontal + Vertial* scrolling.

So, i'm reloading my section like below way,

```
if (isWishListSectionReloadRequires) {
    NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
                                 nil];
    NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
                                 nil];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [tableView endUpdates];
} else {
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

But, i'm facing below crash,

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1054 2016-11-04 04:25:15.921 estimation[9025:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (10) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (10), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 1 deleted)

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason? Any idea would be appreciated!!

Comment: Have you updated the datasource accordingly? I mean the number of rows in a section etc.?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri How do i manually update the datasource?

Comment: Try - (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation instead of deleting and inserting.

Comment: did you tried to reload the first section by calling `reloadSections` method  of tableview ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried that. It crashes

Comment: @Praveen you should also update your data array

Comment: @Praveen it may datasource issue. As you said your first section always displays my Wishlist products then you just need to reload the first section.

Comment: Okay. Let me try that way @Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

You could use UITableView's reloadSections method instead.

**Objective C**

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];                                     
[self.tableView reloadSections:section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

**Swift**

```
tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 2), withRowAnimation: .None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reload Collection View as you need only update the wishlist.

```
[collectionView reloadData];
```

If you need both horizontal and vertical scroll there are many third party lib once checkout [RTTwoDimmensionalScroll](https://github.com/santhosh1993/RTTwoDimensionalScroll)

Answer (score 0):

Reload using the below way, don't forget to reload specific sections inside begin updates and end updates so that headers and footers also gets updated.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];                                     
[self.tableView reloadSections:section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
```